# PosExplorer - barcode scanner - getting error 'Root element is missing' after scanner.Open()

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am programming an application in WPF which initializes posExplorer on a particular page, acquires the required scanner and then open and listen on DataEvent handler. It already worked and there wasn't any problem.
Then it suddenly (yep, suddenly) began to throw exception:

An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in HHSO4NET.dll but was not handled in user code...
Something like 'Root element is missing' [from Czech translation, which I can't change]
And yes, Barcode scanner was connected into computer. I already tried to reinstall pos for net 1.12, but still the same error.

There is code behind this:

```
Private PosExplorer posExplorer = new PosExplorer ();
Private Scanner scan;

PosExplorer.DeviceAddedEvent + = new 
DeviceChangedEventHandler(posExplorer_DeviceAddedEvent);
Var deviceCollection = posExplorer.GetDevices (DeviceType.Scanner);

Foreach (DeviceInfo dInfo in deviceCollection)
{
    If (dInfo.Type == "Scanner" && dInfo.ServiceObjectName == "HoneywellScannerSO")
    {
        If (dInfo.LogicalNames.Length> 0)
        {
             Devicess.Add (dInfo);
        }
    }
}

Scan = (Scanner) posExplorer.CreateInstance (devicess [0]);

If (! (Scan.State == ControlState.Idle))
{
    Scan.Open ();    //AFTER THAT IT FAILS
    Scan.Claim (0);
    Scan.DeviceEnabled = true;
    Scan.DataEvent + = new DataEventHandler (activeScanner_DataEvent);
    Scan.DataEvent = true;
    Scan.DecodeData = true;
}
```

Can somebody tell me, how is possible that it worked and later without any modification in this code it do not work? Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a few days I finally solved it. It required software reinstal from Honeywell - POS4NET Configuration utility. Then remove and again add scanner on specified port and it running. How simple, right? But still dont know why it happened.

Comment: Well, it happed because of debugging...
I can not debug the asynchronous onDataEvent method, because at that stage Windows show messagebox about application closing. At that point, when I did not press 'continue' and do not let Visual Studio complete the closing properly, it did not save the configuration file correctly at some point. So it is necessary to reinstall the honeywell program to create the file again.
I hope it helps to someone.